# How to populate an array with dictionaries containing certain key/values

Tags: ios, arrays, dictionary

I'm working with a plist file at the moment but intend to switch over to json when the backend is finally built. So for the moment my plist is an array that contains a bunch of dictionaries.

I'd like to use this information to create a new array containing only the dictionaries with certain values.

For example. My plist contains a bunch of locations like so:
key: location  value:example place name here
key: type      value:indoor

I want to build an array containing only those with "indoor" set as the type value.
And then perhaps a second one containing all "outdoor" locations.

What's the best way to go about doing this, or perhaps I can be directed to a tutorial of some sort.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply loop through your array and add the qualifying dictionaries to a new array.

```
NSMutableArray *arrayIndoor = [NSMutableArray array];
NSMutableArray *arrayOutdoor = [NSMutableArray array];
NSString *type;
for (NSDictionary *dict in arrayPList) {
    type = [dict objectForKey:@"type"];
    if ([type isEqualToString:@"indoor"]) 
        [arrayIndoor addObject:dict];
    else if ([type isEqualToString:@"indoor"]) 
        [arrayOutdoor addObject:dict];
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Was the answer I ended up going with. A lot less complicated than I thought it would be.

Answer (score 1):

All you are really needing to do is sort the array into two arrays. There isn't a direct method that I have seen that will do this for you. My suggestion would be to use a fast enumeration over the array and conditionally break it into two new arrays.

```
NSMutableArray *locations = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
NSMutableArray *type = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

for (NSDictionary *dict in MyPlistArray) {
    if ([dict valueForKey:@"locationKey"]) {
        [locations addObject:dict];
    } else if ([dict valueForKey:@"typeKey"]) {
        [type addObject:dict];
    }
}
```

You might need to use a different method for determining which key to put in each array, but you get the general idea.

Also I'm assuming that you would want the arrays of dictionaries to persist after, so you can just set those up as properties instead of local variables.

Comment: I believe this only checks the keys, not the values themselves. NVM I saw your comments on it.